# How to render a react element using an html string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var Klass = React.createClass({
  this.props.html_string = '<button>BUTTON_TEXT</button>';
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        {this.props.html_string}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Currently `{this.props.html_string}` gives me a text node.  How can I make this a HTML DOM node?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you want is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

```
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

**Edit:** you'll want to htmlencode the string.

Comment: What do you mean by htmlencode? Could you expand your example? I'm interested in sanitizing the html. Thanks

Comment: I mean use html entities when necessary, like &gt; and &lt; instead of > and <

Answer (score 5):

Also be aware of `React.renderToString('html')` which can be used on server - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

Comment: `React.renderToString()` is now deprecated, use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` now (`import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'`)